# How to do crossdomain calls from Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, web-services

What's needed to succesfully make a crossdomain call from Silverlight?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you would need to have a clientaccesspolicy.xml file in the domain web root of the server that you wish to call (ie www.example.com/clientaccesspolicy.xml) that defines that it is ok for services from other domains to call services on that domain.

Read the [How to Make a Service Available Across Domain Boundaries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197955%28VS.95%29.aspx) MSDN article for more detailed information.

Answer (score 2):

See Jon Galloway's blog post on this as well

http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/12/12/silverlight-crossdomain-access-workarounds.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Intellisense helper file and walk-through: http://silverlight.net/learn/learnvideo.aspx?video=47174

Answer (score 0):

Maybe also check out JSONP http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/107136.aspx for example this is how you can get Twitter updates in JavaScript on the client side even though Twitter is on a different domain than you web page.